# Discord.net get the list of roles for a user

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to get the list of roles for a user inside `MessageReceived` by writing `(message.Author as SocketGuildUser).Roles`. However, the cast always returns null. I also tried using `Context.User` instead, but that returns null too. What am I missing here?

This is the exception I get when I put a breakpoint at the casting line:

`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Discord.WebSocket.SocketGlobalUser' to type 'Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuildUser'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am dumb. I was trying to get the role list inside a DM context when roles only belong to a specific server. The code itself is fine when run in a non-DM context.

Comment: Accept your answer so other people can know that it is solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
foreach(SocketRole role in ((SocketGuildUser)message.Author).Roles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(role.Name);
}
```

Comment: The cast is the problem I'm having as stated in the question. I can't get the roles off a null object. I have rephrased it to be clearer.

Comment: What exactly is `SocketGlobalUser`. I don't see it in the docs. Maybe you should to updating your discord.net package @idlackage

Comment: I'm using the latest stable Discord.net package (v1.0.2). `SocketGlobalUser` should be just `SocketUser` as it's just `message.Author`.